# Articles and Parallelism

Tags: articles, parallelism

What is the best way to understand the difference between articles and parallelism?

I found a good resource on parallelism [here](https://grammarbrain.com/parallelism/).

But there's some missing information on how they work together. I'm learning English and this is confusing for me. I'm a native Spanish speaker.

Comment: The link does not mention articles besides other articles on the subject. Did you mean *a* peach and *the* house?

Comment: That's right, the website *does not* have this information. I'm looking for help on it. And yes, those types of articles. I keep seeing "articles and parallelism" in homework but I don't understand.

Comment: Hello, Steve. Not a bad article, but I wouldn't say it's perfect. 'The tailoring class was a good place for learning to stitch clothes and to make new friends.' means 'The tailoring class was a good place for learning to stitch clothes and for learning to make new friends.' I assume that what was intended is 'The tailoring class was a good place for learning to stitch clothes, and also  for making new friends.' More complicated sentences need greater care,

Comment: Umm. The difference between articles and parallelism is that articles are a class of words used in certainly contexts, and parallelism is a description of certain kinds of grammatical or logical or semantic structure. What is the difference between fish and swimming?

Comment: You may find searches for 'conjunction reduction', and for 'deletion', especially on ELU, useful, Steve.

Comment: I've CV'd because I find this question much too broad. "Parallelism" and "articles" are entirely different kinds of things, as noted above, so many things can be said about the differences between them. If you have a specific concern, please identify it.

Comment: The two topics aren't related, so the difference is everything other than both being about language. Did you mean something other than "articles"?

Comment: If fish and swimming doesn't cover it, examples of bad parallels may help: I'd like the bronzini and to see a movie. To err is human, forgiving is also appreciated. You either want it, or she does. Good: I'd like an apple and the pear there [that's two articles that make sense without being the same.]

Comment: Could you please clarify what about articles you associate with parallelism? Articles are used in many different kinds of constructions in English, including both parallel and non-parallel forms. Can you edit into the question some examples of sentences that are confusing you, and explain what you find confusing about them, please? As written this question is too broad to answer.